# Чтение определённых строк из текстового файла

Tags: c#

Нужно считать из текстового файла несколько строк (допустим, три), начиная с "заголовочной" строки. Текст в файле такого вида (простите за громоздкость):

```
02.12.2015   
аааааааааааааааааааааааааааа

19.12.2015  
пппппппппппппппппппппппппппп

26.12.2015  
фффффффффффффффффффф

10.12.2015  
яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя
```

И нужно считать строку с определённой датой (допустим, 19.12.2015) и следующие две строчки (забитую буквами "п" и пустую), при этом проигнорировав предыдущие три строки и все последующие. Ума не приложу, как это сделать. Попытался сделать вот так:

```
int n = 0; // переменная, отвечающая за номер строки в файле
string dateline = textBox1.Text; // считываем дату из текстбокса, в нашем случае это 19.12.2015
string text = File.ReadAllText("Zametka.txt"); // читаем текст файла
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Zametka.txt"))
{
     string line; // промежуточная переменная для StreamReader'а
     if (text.Contains(dateline)) // если текст файла содержит нужную строку
     {
           while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != dateline) // то, пока она не будет достигнута, 
                {
                    n++; // итерируем счётчик
                }
           IEnumerable<string> note = File.ReadLines("Zametka.txt").Skip(n).Take(3); // и читаем, начиная с нужной нам строки с датой и на три вперёд
           string notee = Convert.ToString(note); // переводим IEnumerable string в обычный стринг
           textBox2.Text = notee; // выводим результат поиска в текстбокс
     }
}
```

Но это не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetLineSets(string fileName, string neededWord)
        {
            var template = new Regex("([^\n]+|)" + neededWord + "([^\n]+|)\n([^\n]+|)\n([^\n]+|)");

            var aa = template.Matches(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
            foreach (Match item in aa)
            {
                yield return item.Value;
            }
        }
```

Вот таким способом можно сделать через регулярные выражения, просто ищем строки типа 
"строка с нужным словом + строка + еще строка"

в таком случае будет даже лучше работать, т.к. даже если нашло строку с словом, а следующая тоже с этим словом - то он вернет строку 1 2 3 и 2 3 4. И работает через yield, что придаст компактности всему :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! У вас получилось действительно очень компактно и, самое главное, функционально! А я же сделал то же самое на основе того, что вы подсказали мне сначала, только ещё прикручивал костыли: проверку повторяющейся строки, перекомпоновка текста. А вы то же самое уместили в четыре строчки кода. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял и вам нужно получить строку с датой, а после этого две следующие строки, то можно просто сделать так

```
public static string GetLines(string filePath, string neededDate)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string temp;
                while (true)
                {
                    temp = reader.ReadLine();
                    if(temp.Contains(neededDate))
                    {
                        temp += reader.ReadLine() + "\n";
                        temp += reader.ReadLine() + "\n";
                        return temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Если вы считываете весь текст из файла сразу - можно через LINQ сделать, если нужно - могу показать, как

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите, мне хотелось бы сделать это через LINQ, поскольку нужно читать весь текст (ведь могут дублироваться даты), конечно, если это не слишком сложно.